# How to move files from server to FTP Backup storage?

Tags: linux, database, server, gnu

i have a dedicated server and 100GB ftp backup server, now i compressed my file into tar.gz.bz2 in dedicated server /root , now i want to move this files to my ftp backup storage, how do i do it ?
my host recommended me to use ncftp.

ps: i am using dedicated server from online.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install ncftp client, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ncftp
```

The syntax is as follows:

```
ncftpput ftp-host-name /path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir
ncftpput -options ftp-host-name /path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir
```

Here’s how to use ncftpput to upload a file:

```
ncftp -u username -p password www.hostname.com path/to/remote/file path/to/local/file
```

Try the ncftpput client command as follows:

```
ncftpput -R -v -u "username" ftp.gnu.biz /gnu/forum /tmp/pbb
```

Where,

-u "username" : Ftp server username

-v : Verbose i.e. show upload progress

-R : Recursive mode; copy whole directory trees.
ftp.gnu.biz : Remote ftp server (use FQDN or IP).

/gnu/forum : Remote ftp server directory where all files and subdirectories will be uploaded.

/tmp/pbb : Local directory (or list of files) to upload remote ftp server directory /gnu/forum

Or log in to the server:

```
ncftp -u username -p password ftp.gnu.biz
```

and when inside the ftp shell:

```
put -R somedir
```